# Where to buy winter clothes in Rome , Italy?

Tags: italy, clothing, winter

There are good places to shop winter clothes in Rome?
It will probably be at winter season (January).

Good, I means, good quality with good price (fair price).

Comment: what is a good price? It is very relative. You could be give more details. Also, please, read some tips how create good questions: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Hi, @MarcelP , well I don't see much what explain here, good price is just a price where most of people can afford as common sense. Just what everybody looks, get good clothes for fair prices.

Comment: @ceinmart Think eg. of the wide span of possible incomes around the world ... What an Italian thinks as normal can't be bought with an average Gambian income. A "good price" for you is anything between "basically free" and "needs years of savings" for others.